# Gaussian filter of 2d image with location dependant sigma in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy, theano

I am trying to implement in Python a Gaussian filter in which the kernel is 
[image]

where  `f(x,y)` is some function of the coordinates. Is it possible somehow to trick [scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter.html) to do the job?

Eventually I will have to perform the following integration over space:

[image]

And so I get $\tilde G(x',y') $ as a coordinate dependent coefficient.

Right now I am making it with tedious `for` loops:

```
def calc_g1(b,w,p):
    nx,ny = b.shape
    g1 = np.zeros_like(b)
    for i in np.arange(nx):
        for j in np.arange(ny):
            for ii in np.arange(nx):
                for jj in np.arange(ny):
                    g = calc_kernel(b,p,i,j,ii,jj)
                    g[i,j]+=g*w[ii,jj]
    return g1


def calc_kernel(b,w,i,j,ii,jj):
    dx,dy = p['dx'],p['dy']
    dist_x = dx*np.abs(ii-i)
    dist_y = dy*np.abs(jj-j)
    dist = dist_x**2 + dist_y**2
    f = (1.0 + p['eta']*b[i,j])**2
    return 1.0/(2.0*np.pi)*np.exp(-(dist)/(2.0*f))
```

** Can I do it somehow using Symbolic calculation using SymPy or Theano?

Comment: Certainly not symbolically. Even if your formula for w is pretty simple, chances are there is no close form for its convolution with G.

Answer (score 1):

Convolutions, from a certain signal and filter support size onwards are always faster to perform in Fourier space by pointwise multiplication of the Fourier transforms of signal and filter and inverse transforming.

In that case one assumes the filtering to be linear and shift-invariant, so your context does not fit the classic context of convolution.

So you will have to implement this yourself.

If you have a lot of signals to apply this to, your best bet without resorting to writing low-level code is to write this transformation in the form of a `scipy.sparse` matrix. For this, you have to create all the Gaussian filters you need and place them appropriately in the image and stacking the ravelled versions of these filter images in a sparse matrix. You should truncate the support of you Gaussians so most of the pixels of your image are equal to 0. Once this matrix is created, you can apply it immediately to the pixel array of any image to get the desired result.

Comment: I have explored the option of implementing a fast algorithm for convolution integrals - http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jcp.2005.12.003 . But I hope that there is another way using SciPy convolution methods..

Comment: Article is behind paywall. I think all convolution methods in scipy are shift-invariant. If you want to use them, the only way I see is to distort the image in a way that the convolution can stay shift-invariant. But that seems a mess.